# Cannot link html/css pages

Tags: html, css

I have 3 pages:

- index.html
- pages/top-ten.html
- pages/contact.html

My CSS code is in

- css/css.css

Everything is fine with the `index.html` but when I copy the code to the other 2 pages the CSS isn't responding to that.

I'll attach snippets of the code [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eolTj.png)

Comment: did you add the link to the stylesheet on each page?

Comment: Next time please show us the necessary code information directly as code (not as image).  It is much easier to copy & paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/css.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/css.css">
```

This will find the css file from those files which are one level deeper in the `pages` folder.

Comment: thank you! So if its ever in a folder it will need an extra"." ?

Comment: Exactly, the `../` means one level up, while `./` means in the same folder